# Why is my first Nodejs http PUT request working, while the second and subsequent time out?

Tags: node.js, put, http-request

I've been battling this for some time. I have a set of mocha test cases, in which I am testing a REST API. To do this, I am sending HTTP PUT requests and receiving the responses.

I am using the Async library for control logic flow, specifically the waterfall in this model.

The first PUT request goes through just fine, and I get the expected response from the server.

If I duplicate the exact same code, the second PUT request times out. It gets to the http.req() line and doesn't print the console.log() message there, so somehow the request is being skipped over, maybe?

Help figuring out where this is going awry appreciated.

Here's a relevant snippet example from my mocha test case:

```
async.waterfall([
        function someFunction(cb) {
            var cmd = url.parse('http://<my_ip>:<my_port>/some/command');

            cmd.headers = {};
            cmd.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            cmd.method = 'PUT';

            console.log('command:', cmd);

            var req = http.request(cmd, function (res) {
                console.log('sending some command at ' + cmd.href);

                res.on('data', function (dataChunk) {
                    console.log('dataChunk:', dataChunk.toString());
                });

                res.on('end', function () {
// This logs, and completes correctly
                    console.log('done sending some command');
                    var statusCode = res.statusCode;

                    cb(null, statusCode);
                });

                res.on('error', function (e) {
                    console.error('Problem with response: ' + e.message);
                    cb(e, null);
                });
            });

            req.on('error', function(e) {
                console.error('problem with request: ' + e.message);
                cb(e, null);
            });

            req.end();
        },
function someFunctionDupe(statusCode, cb) {
            var cmd = url.parse('http://<my_ip>:<my_port>/some/command');

            cmd.headers = {};
            cmd.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            cmd.method = 'PUT';

            console.log('command:', cmd);

            var req = http.request(cmd, function (res) {
// This line never executes:
                console.log('sending some command at ' + cmd.href);

                res.on('data', function (dataChunk) {
                    console.log('dataChunk:', dataChunk.toString());
                });

                res.on('end', function () {
                    console.log('done sending some command');
                    var statusCode = res.statusCode;

                    cb(null, statusCode);
                });

                res.on('error', function (e) {
                    console.error('Problem with response: ' + e.message);
                    cb(e, null);
                });
            });

            req.on('error', function(e) {
                console.error('problem with request: ' + e.message);
                cb(e, null);
            });

            req.end();
        },
// code continues
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile checking you can make successive `PUT` requests to your REST API using another client to rule out the server misbehaving.

Comment: And no error message? You say it is "skipped over" perhaps, are subsequent functions in your waterfall array being executed? Are you using the final error function in waterfall to see if you get any error there?